# Deploy .exe files created using PyInstaller and associate icons

Tags: python, deployment, installation, pyinstaller, setup-deployment

I have my .exe file built by PyInstaller for my application (using PyQt). How do I deploy my package now? I want to create a setup installer (with GUI) for my application (for Windows Users).

PyInstaller allows for a custom icon for my .exe file. However, I would like to associate certain other file types with custom icons as well, similarly like how Photoshop and .psd, .abr (Brushes) files, etc.. have different icons associated with them. Is there a way to achieve this as a part of the deployment process?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend Inno setup for creating instalation from pyinstaller build.

http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php